# What does "and' mean in C++

Tags: c++, logical-operators

I know this has been asked elsewhere, but I can't find it because of the ambiguity between the and operator '&' and the actual word in C++.  I am learning C++ and came across a helper function in hackerrank that had a line that confused me.

```
return x == y and x == ' '
```

I am not sure what the "and" does.  Googling it only returns references to the "&" operator.

The whole function is below; the "and" is in line 3:

```
vector<string> split_string(string input_string) {
    string::iterator new_end = unique(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), [] (const char &x, const char &y) {
        return x == y and x == ' ';
    });
    input_string.erase(new_end, input_string.end());
    while (input_string[input_string.length() - 1] == ' ') {
        input_string.pop_back();
    }
    vector<string> splits;
    char delimiter = ' ';
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t pos = input_string.find(delimiter);
    while (pos != string::npos) {
        splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, pos - i));
        i = pos + 1;
        pos = input_string.find(delimiter, i);
    }
    splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, min(pos, input_string.length()) - i + 1));
    return splits;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These keywords were used when developers were using keyboards which didn't support characters like `&&` or `||`. Using a keyword instead for these operators would resolve that issue.

In this case `and` is the same as writing `&&`.

Here is a full list of the keywords:

> and   &&
>
> and_eq    &=
>
> bitand    &
>
> bitor |
>
> compl ~
>
> not   !
>
> not_eq    !=
>
> or    ||
>
> or_eq |=
>
> xor   ^
>
> xor_eq    ^=

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens

Comment: They seem to be keywords in C++, not macros. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and

Answer (score 1):

`and` is a (not well known) C++ alternative operator and a synonym for `&&`. It exists because C/C++ code can be written in a file with non-ASCII-7 character set/encoding. Therefore C/C++ support alternative commands for operators like `&`, `~`, etc.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Edit: encoding problem